# Problems with horizontal scroll in a p-multiselect (Angular and Sass) it works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, sass, primeng

I am trying to add a horizontal scroll to a p-multiSelect (primeng) so that the selected elements are displayed horizontally.

I have managed to get this horizontal scroll to show in Chrome and Firefox on Mac, but it only shows in Firefox on Windows, I can't get it to show in Chrome.

I attach the code:

```
`.p-multiselect-label {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
  }

 .p-multiselect-items-wrapper {
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 10px;
  }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-button:increment,
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    display: none;
  }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #797979;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #f1f2f3;
  }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 10px;
  }
}`
```

This is how it looks in firefox with the horizontal scroll, how can I make it look the same in chrome?

[image]